# How can I fetch information from the previous page and direct it to the correct page in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, query-string

I have two html files named list.html and detail.html. I am fetching title and body datas from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and display them in a posts.html screen like this:

[posts.html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlV79.png)

here below is my posts.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="post">
            <a>
                <h3 class="title"> </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="body"> </p>
        </div>
        <script src="fetch.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

And here below is my javascript code which I use in posts.html:

```
const api_url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

async function getISS(){
   const response = await fetch(api_url);
   const data= await response.json();
   let post = document.getElementById("post");
   
   for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      const { id, title, body } = data[i]
      post.innerHTML += `<a href="detail.html">
      <h3 class="title">${title}</h3></a>
      <p class="body">${body} </p>`
   }
}  

getISS();
```

What I want to do is when I click a post's title,  detail.htm screen should open and it should only display title and body of clicked post. For example, from the posts.html output picture above , when I click "qui est esse" title, it should direct me to detail.html and only display "qui est esse"s title and body like this:

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHdza.png)

But if I click the second post "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut" title, it should direct me to detail.html screen again but this time it should only display ea "molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut" title and body.

here below is my detail.html code but there isn't anything important yet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Detail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Body</p>
        <script src="detail-script.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I am new to the html-js world. I think I need to do this with query string but so far, I am not able to achieve this. I am suppose to use only native javascript. I can't use Andy framework. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you post a parsed version of both sites? As it sounds now, it does not sound like a JS task at all. Probably a simple anchor that leads to a specific ID will be sufficient. Then use `:target` pseudo-selector to only show the targeted element CSS wise

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and a bit of a clumsy fix but you can add a parameter to the anchor tag like with a question mark in the url (it doesn't change anything but allows data to be sent from your posts.html file to your detail.html file. Kinda like this :

```
post.innerHTML += `<a href="detail.html?title=${title}">
  <h3 class="title">${title}</h3></a>
  <p class="body">${body} </p>`
```

and if all of the titles for the placeholdes are unique, then you can only display the unique title passed from posts.html in detail.html like this in your async function:

```
const urlString = window.location.href;
const url = new URL(urlString);
const titleString = url.searchParams.get("title")
for (let i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
   const { id, title, body } = data[i]
   if (titleString === title) {
       post.innerHTML += `<a href="detail.html?title=${title}">
       <h3 class="title">${title}</h3></a>
       <p class="body">${body} </p>`
   }
}
```